# How do I change compiler on Xcode to gcc 7.3.0?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I currently have Xcode 6.2.

First is there a way to check if this version of Xcode comes with gcc 7.3.0? And if it does have gcc 7.3.0, how do I set up Xcode so that gcc 7.3.0 becomes the default compiler?

However if my Xcode does not have gcc 7.3.0 how do I get gcc 7.3 and set up Xcode so that gcc 7.3.0 becomes the default compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode uses the LLVM Clang compiler, not gcc. gcc can be installed, the easiest way would be using either [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org). I'm not sure if there's any way to make it the default compiler though, especially not to use from inside Xcode. Is there some specific feature/reason why you need gcc 7.3?

Comment: I tried getting Homebrew but towards the end there were a couple of errors that showed up on terminal but I dont remember the exact wording I just remember they were errors. I need gcc 7.3 for school.

Comment: clang aims for (virtually) full compatibility with gcc, I would try to use clang instead of installing gcc. Unless you need very new C++ features, the version you have should work. Also, Xcode 6.2 is quite old, are you stuck using macOS 10.9 for some reason?